# Major Upgrade in WiX installer not working following a UIRef change

Tags: visual-studio, installation, wix

I have changed a UIRef tag between versions of my deployment.

from Version 1.0:   `<UIRef ID="WixUI_FeatureTree" />`
to Version 2.0:   `<UIRef ID="WixUI_Advanced" />`

Wix Version 3.6

Now, when I run the Version 2.0 installer, it does not detect
the previous version, so instead of uninstalling during the upgrade
it installs a new version next to the existing version.

Intermediate versions upgraded fine (1.0->1.1->1.2).

**The major changes in 2.0 are:**

1. A new sub-feature under the main

   Change to the UIRef from WixUI_FeatureTree, to WixUI_Advanced
    to allow deployment to select from 'AllUsers' and 'Single User'

**Remove Existing Products is defined as:**

```
<InstallExecuteSequence>      
     <RemoveExistingProducts After='InstallInitialize' />

      <Custom Action=...
    ...
```

**My product is defined as:**

```
#UpgradeCode# is consistent between versions
#ProductId# is changed between versions

<Product Id="#ProductId"
  UpgradeCode="#UpgradeCode#"
  Name="!(loc.ApplicationName)"
  Language="1033"
  Codepage="1252"
  Version="2.0.0"
  Manufacturer="!(loc.Manufacturer)">    
     <Package 
          Id="*"
          InstallerVersion="300" 
          InstallPrivileges="elevated"      
          Languages="1033"
          Compressed="yes"
          InstallScope="perMachine"
          Manufacturer="!(loc.Manufacturer)"
          SummaryCodepage="1252"
          Platform="x86"      
          Description="!(loc.ApplicationName)"/>
           <Upgrade Id="#UpgradeCode#">
           <UpgradeVersion OnlyDetect="no" Property="PREVIOUSFOUND"
                           Minimum="1.0.0" IncludeMinimum="yes"
                           Maximum="2.0.0" IncludeMaximum="no"/>
           </Upgrade>
```

I am wondering if there is something that I can do
to force the installer to check the upgrade and perform
remove of previous version that is no longer being handled
following my changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the build log I noticed:

> MSI (c) (6C:C4) [12:04:44:624]: FindRelatedProducts: current install is per-user.  Related install for product '{PRODUCT-GUID }' is per-machine.  Skipping...
>   Action ended 12:04:44: FindRelatedProducts. Return value 1.

I had removed:

```
 <Product ... InstallScope="perMachine" ... />
```

when upgrading versions.

I did not realize that upgrade matching included the `InstallScope` Property of Product.

I can still install per-user using `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Advanced" />`, so this property does not seem to affect the selection of `PerMachine` or `PerUser`, so I have put it back in. Upgrade now works again.